# angularjs - update table column when model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

i have a dataTable that i define dynamically, based on my controller's model, as following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rec in grid.records">
        <td ng-repeat="col in grid.columns" 
            ng-init="value=rec[col.name]">
            <span ng-model="rec[col.name]">{{value}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

why doesn't dataTable column values is updated when model changes?

Comment: Why are you using `ng-model` for a non-input element?

Comment: Yes-yes, I would advice to read about ngModel: [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: actually, i wasn't using ng-model, but after a few tries, i've tried to use it.

Comment: anyway, my code without 'ng-model' supposed to work?

Comment: From Angular Docs: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat" `rec[col.name]` is not a special property. An example of a special property would be `$index`.

Comment: I think the real problem is your data structure. Is `rec` a linear array, and if not, why not? Instead of looping through `col in grid.columns`, can you loop through `col in rec`?

Comment: @Blazemonger, i can't loop through rec, because it has properties that i can't write into table, only properties contained in columns can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rec in grid.records">
        <td ng-repeat="col in grid.columns">
            <span>{{rec[col.name]}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: i have created a isolated case, using {{rec[col.name]}} instead of {{value}}, and it works. Thank you very much. If my real application keep not working out, i'll let you know.

Comment: the whole problem was how i did use `ng-init`. Thanks.